# convert json Map<String,dynamic> to list

Tags: flutter, dart

i need to convert my Map to list using objects(constructor) using Http post method.

https://app.quicktype.io?share=mkGKqWoXsZJrJH4JTtGt

Comment: add whatever code you have and facing error. did you encoded data before senfing?

Comment: I don't have a idea to do this??

Comment: Tell any way of do this or any packages